# Tizen Web App: when watching video(html5) mobile device enters into sleep mode after 10-20 minuets

Tags: html, video, sleep, tizen

When I've tried to publish my tizen web app I was rejected. There is the purpose:

*Defect*

The application goes to sleep mode even if it is executed without touch.

*Procedure*

1. Execute the `application>>Start` to watch some movie
2. Do not touch the screen
3. Check whether the application goes to sleep mode

*Expected Result*

The application should not go to sleep mode because the user wants to execute it without touch.

I think that this is a tizen webkit bug. Nevertheless I've tried to request `CPU_AWAKE` and `SCREEN_NORMAL` power state programmatically. And this wasn't helped to me. Is this really a bug or I do something wrong?

Device: Ref.Device-PQ. Tizen version: 2.2.0

Comment: `tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");` should prevent this from happening. see [docs](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/tutorials/sys_tutorial/managing_power_state.htm) for more details, you can also use `setScreenStateChangeListener()` example to monitor changes in state. There is not enough information about your app to tell anything more ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But power request doesn't solve my problem. More information about bug here : 

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/when-watching-videohtml5-mobile-device-enters-sleep-mode-after-10-20-minuets

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the screenStateChange event and when this occurs, you can set screen to turn on.
I listen for the dim state and reset the screen to on state.

```
function onScreenStateChanged(previousState, changedState) {
        //alert("Screen state changed from " + previousState + " to " + changedState);
        if (changedState == "SCREEN_DIM"   ){
            //tizen.power.restoreScreenBrightness();
            tizen.power.turnScreenOn();
        }       
}
tizen.power.setScreenStateChangeListener(onScreenStateChanged);
```